# 3D plot of galaxy or universe

Tags: r, 3d, plot

Is R code available for creating 3D plots of our galaxy or universe?  I have searched a few times over the last six months and not found any.

This news article includes some very nice 3D plots that look like they may have been created with R:

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2341750/The-beautiful-3D-map-space-plots-nearest-galaxies--reminds-tiny-Earth-is.html

A short video can be viewed at the above link, but I do not see a link to R code there.  The video was created by people at the University of Lyon and the University of Hawaii.  Here is a link to a longer video related to the same project:

http://irfu.cea.fr/cosmography

I just thought it would be neat to explore space from within a 3D plot in R but I cannot find any relevant code.

Locations for objects likely are found within the Redshift Catalog, and perhaps can be downloaded, but I have no idea whether I would need to adjust those location data in various ways if I tried to create my own 3D map.  Here is one possible source of data if I were to try creating my own map:

https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~dfabricant/huchra/zcat/

I have read something to the effect that asking for relevant packages does not make for an appropriate post.  Sorry if this post is not appropriate.

Comment: The problem is not the code but the data: find the data and then you can write some code.

Comment: `rgl` provides the 3D rendering. If you got the x, y, z coordinates or the distances between stars (=> `cmdscale()`), it should be possible without too much effort (?).

Comment: It is relatively easy to plot points inside a 3d cube with `rgl`. 2d projections of vector fields? Possibly with ggplot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936504/vector-field-visualisation-r. No idea beyond that, though.

Comment: You might also be interested in Celestia: http://portableapps.com/apps/education/celestia_portable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the modelling but the data. Here's a database made available by . http://www.stellar-database.com/isdb.mdb - but probably you'll need to dig around for what you want specifically.

Here's a simple SQL query to pull out some of the star data:

```
SELECT Positions.OwnerID, Positions.RA_hr, Positions.RA_min, Positions.RA_sec, Positions.Dec_deg, Positions.Dec_arcmin, Positions.Dec_arcsec, Positions.Distance, Spectra.SpectralClass, Spectra.LuminosityClass, qryProps.Name
FROM (Positions LEFT JOIN Spectra ON Positions.OwnerID = Spectra.OwnerID) LEFT JOIN qryProps ON Positions.OwnerID = qryProps.OwnerID
WHERE (((Positions.Distance)>=0));
```

Then save it as a csv and import it:

```
stars<-read.csv("qNamedStars.txt",header=T)
head(stars)
```

Write a function to translate the coords to X, Y, Z

```
celCoords<-function(Rh,Rm,Rs,Da,Dm,Ds,Distance){
  R.angle<-((Rh/24)+(Rm/(24*60))+(Rm/(24*60*60)))*2*pi
  D.angle<-(Da/90)+(Dm/(90*60))+(Ds/(90*60*60))*0.5*pi
  Z<-cos(D.angle)*Distance
  hyp.XY<-sin(D.angle)*Distance
  X<-sin(R.angle)*hyp.XY
  Y<-cos(R.angle)*hyp.XY
  return(c(X,Y,Z))
}

starcoords<-cbind(stars,
      matrix(celCoords(stars$RA_hr,
          stars$RA_min,
          stars$RA_sec,
          stars$Dec_deg,
          stars$Dec_arcmin,
          stars$Dec_arcsec,
          stars$Distance
          ),,ncol=3,byrow=T)
        )

colnames(starcoords)<-c(colnames(stars),"X","Y","Z")
```

Filter the data.frame

```
sf<-starcoords[abs(starcoords$Z)<2000 &  abs(starcoords$X)<1000,] # apply a filter
```

Then plot using `rgl`

```
require(rgl)
plot3d(sf$X,sf$Y,sf$Z,col=rainbow(nrow(sf)),size=10)
```

[image]

You can obviously add more data for luminosity, size, type, etc. if it's available, and then use those parameters to set size, color, etc.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Although I have never used SQL.  Could you recommend a free source of SQL or do I simply need to install an R package to make the query?

Comment: her;s the text file (probably easier), <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85i6kIzoV0odkxlbWZxa1pVTzQ/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: And here's a file with the larger galactic data (although not all have names, etc.) <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85i6kIzoV0oX2hIVUtGUUJqM3c/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: If the post is deleted I will move it and your answer to my Wikipedia users page and to my github site.