# How do I calculate the gradient of a matrix to draw a vector field in R?

Tags: r

I looked around, but all I could find was how to find the derivative of a matrix using `diff(d)`, where `d` is a matrix. This doesn't give me vectors, just a bunch of scalars. I'm not really sure what to do with those.

I'd like to find a way to calculate the gradient at a few points throughout the surface that is represented by a matrix. This gradient can be displayed as a vector field. There's a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936504/vector-field-visualisation-r) about making vector fields in R, but I don't know how to calculate the gradient.

Edit: I will try to elaborate on what I'm looking for. Let's say I have a matrix like this:

```
     X0 X1.5 X3.1 X4.3 X5.9 X7.3 X8.6 X9.8  X11 X12.3 X13.6 X14.9 X16.4 X17.9 X20
 [1,]  0  1.4  3.0  4.5  6.0  7.3  8.6  9.7 10.9  12.2  13.4  14.9  16.4  18.1  20
 [2,]  0  1.6  3.2  4.9  6.4  7.6  8.7  9.6 10.6  11.8  13.2  14.7  16.4  18.1  20
 [3,]  0  1.7  3.5  5.2  7.0  8.3  9.0  9.4  9.9  11.1  12.7  14.6  16.3  18.2  20
 [4,]  0  1.8  3.7  5.8  8.0  9.3  9.3  9.3  9.4  10.2  12.1  14.1  16.2  18.0  20
 [5,]  0  1.7  3.9  6.0  8.8  9.3  9.3  9.4  9.6   9.9  11.8  14.0  16.2  18.1  20
 [6,]  0  1.8  3.8  5.7  8.1  9.3  9.3  9.4  9.6  10.1  12.3  14.4  16.3  18.0  20
 [7,]  0  1.6  3.5  5.2  7.0  8.4  9.1  9.5 10.1  11.3  13.0  14.6  16.4  18.2  20
 [8,]  0  1.5  3.2  4.9  6.4  7.7  8.7  9.7 10.7  11.9  13.3  14.9  16.5  18.3  20
 [9,]  0  1.5  3.1  4.6  6.0  7.4  8.6  9.7 10.9  12.1  13.5  15.1  16.6  18.3  20
[10,]  0  1.5  3.0  4.6  6.0  7.3  8.5  9.7 10.9  12.4  13.6  13.1  16.6  18.2  20
```

It looks something like this when you plot it:

[image: 3D Surface of the above matrix]

Now, what I want is simply this: at certain intervals of x and y, I'd like to be able to find the slope of the surface. So for example, starting with x=0, y=0, I'd like to find the slope in the form of a vector I can use to plot later. Then, find the slope at x=0, y=1, and so on for all values of y. Then find all the values of y for x=1, and so on.

The purpose of this is to have a bunch of vectors that can be plotted in a vector field [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#mediaviewer/File:Irrotationalfield.svg).

Can this be done in R?

Comment: can you be a little more specific/give a reproducible example?  Do you want to compute gradients only at grid points, or do you want to be able to compute gradients at arbitrary points?  Linear interpolation (assume piecewise linearity)?  What do you want to assume about boundary conditions?

Comment: @BenBolker I expanded a bit on my question.

Comment: Maybe you want the `slope` and `aspect` functionality from the `terrain` function in the `raster` package? The "slope" gives you the magnitude and "aspect" the direction.

Comment: @Spacedman, to make a vector field plot you'd have to re-convert slope and aspect back to dx/dy anyway ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some stuff to start with.

```
m <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3)
```

You have to decide whether to fill in NA or 0 at the beginning or the end, or replicate the first or last value in `diff(x)`, or ...

```
bdiff <- function(x) c(NA,diff(x))
```

Gradients in the x (row) direction:

```
t(apply(m,1,bdiff))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   NA    3    3
## [2,]   NA    3    3
## [3,]   NA    3    3
```

In the y (column) direction:

```
apply(m,2,bdiff)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   NA   NA   NA
## [2,]    1    1    1
## [3,]    1    1    1
```

For your example, something approximately like this works:

```
m2 <- matrix(c(
0,1.4,3.0,4.5,6.0,7.3,8.6,9.7,10.9,12.2,13.4,14.9,16.4,18.1,20,
0,1.6,3.2,4.9,6.4,7.6,8.7,9.6,10.6,11.8,13.2,14.7,16.4,18.1,20,
0,1.7,3.5,5.2,7.0,8.3,9.0,9.4,9.9,11.1,12.7,14.6,16.3,18.2,20,
0,1.8,3.7,5.8,8.0,9.3,9.3,9.3,9.4,10.2,12.1,14.1,16.2,18.0,20,
0,1.7,3.9,6.0,8.8,9.3,9.3,9.4,9.6,9.9,11.8,14.0,16.2,18.1,20,
0,1.8,3.8,5.7,8.1,9.3,9.3,9.4,9.6,10.1,12.3,14.4,16.3,18.0,20,
0,1.6,3.5,5.2,7.0,8.4,9.1,9.5,10.1,11.3,13.0,14.6,16.4,18.2,20,
0,1.5,3.2,4.9,6.4,7.7,8.7,9.7,10.7,11.9,13.3,14.9,16.5,18.3,20,
0,1.5,3.1,4.6,6.0,7.4,8.6,9.7,10.9,12.1,13.5,15.1,16.6,18.3,20,
0,1.5,3.0,4.6,6.0,7.3,8.5,9.7,10.9,12.4,13.6,13.1,16.6,18.2,20),
byrow=TRUE,nrow=10)

rr <- row(m2)
cc <- col(m2)
dx <- t(apply(m2,1,bdiff))
dy <- apply(m2,2,bdiff)
sc <- 0.25
off <- -0.5 ## I *think* this is right since we NA'd row=col=1
plot(rr,cc,col="gray",pch=16)
arrows(rr+off,cc+off,rr+off+sc*dx,cc+off+sc*dy,length=0.05)
```

Comment: first differencing is the discrete analogue of differentiation ... unless I'm completely misunderstanding the OP's question ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Forgive my ignorance, but I'm still unclear on what some of these functions are doing, so I will try to get this working once I read up on them a bit.

Comment: There's also https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#vectorplot for raster objects

Comment: @Spacedman, I don't see an obvious/easy way to (naively) follow the `vectorplot` example without specifying a projection ... ?

Comment: Oops, ignore that message. I forgot that you defined it in the answer!

Comment: It works beautifully. I'm going to be spending some time figuring out how this all works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

Here's the `raster` package approach. Start with the same matrix as Ben's answer:

```
m2 <- matrix(c(
0,1.4,3.0,4.5,6.0,7.3,8.6,9.7,10.9,12.2,13.4,14.9,16.4,18.1,20,
0,1.6,3.2,4.9,6.4,7.6,8.7,9.6,10.6,11.8,13.2,14.7,16.4,18.1,20,
0,1.7,3.5,5.2,7.0,8.3,9.0,9.4,9.9,11.1,12.7,14.6,16.3,18.2,20,
0,1.8,3.7,5.8,8.0,9.3,9.3,9.3,9.4,10.2,12.1,14.1,16.2,18.0,20,
0,1.7,3.9,6.0,8.8,9.3,9.3,9.4,9.6,9.9,11.8,14.0,16.2,18.1,20,
0,1.8,3.8,5.7,8.1,9.3,9.3,9.4,9.6,10.1,12.3,14.4,16.3,18.0,20,
0,1.6,3.5,5.2,7.0,8.4,9.1,9.5,10.1,11.3,13.0,14.6,16.4,18.2,20,
0,1.5,3.2,4.9,6.4,7.7,8.7,9.7,10.7,11.9,13.3,14.9,16.5,18.3,20,
0,1.5,3.1,4.6,6.0,7.4,8.6,9.7,10.9,12.1,13.5,15.1,16.6,18.3,20,
0,1.5,3.0,4.6,6.0,7.3,8.5,9.7,10.9,12.4,13.6,13.1,16.6,18.2,20),
byrow=TRUE,nrow=10)
```

Convert to a raster (note the transpose and general fiddling is because matrices start from the top left but coordinates work from the bottom right):

```
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)
r=raster(t(m2[,ncol(m2):1]), xmn=0.5,xmx=nrow(m2)+.5, ymn=0.5,ymx=ncol(m2)+0.5)
```

Now as Ben hinted, you *do* need to give it a coordinate system. At the moment it just has numeric row and column coordinates from 1 to 10 and 1 to 15. If this was a real-world map then `raster` needs to know if this is lat-long, or metres, or feet, and whether the X coordinates and Y coordinates are on the same scale. This is important, even for data that *isnt* mapped to the real-world like I suspect your data is.

Gradient is meaningless if your X and Y coordinates aren't in the same units. If X is resistance in ohms and Y is current in amps and Z is your measured potential in Volts then what's the slope? Well, it might be 2V per ohm on the X axis and -3V per amp in the Y direction. So altogether? You can't say, because you can't combine ohms and amps to get a direction.

So I'll take the assumption that whatever the units of X and Y are in your example, they are the same units (maybe they are ohms on resistor A and ohms on resistor B) and they go from 1 to 10 and 1 to 15.

Now I think there's a projection code that just says "These are x and y coordinates with no real geographic meaning" but I can't remember what it is or find it. So I'll just lie, and use any old coordinate reference system that I know is a regular Cartesian grid. In this case, the GB National Grid. If you tried to plot this raster on a map it would be a tiny square off the coast of south-west England, because that's where the grid origin is, and your data is 10m by 15m in this system:

```
projection(r)=CRS("+init=epsg:27700")
```

Let's plot it to make sure we haven't messed up yet:

```
persp(r,theta=-50,phi=20, shade=0.23,col="red")
```

[image: persepctive view of sample data]

note that the X and Y coordinates are pointing in the same direction as your sample plot, so I know I've got this all right so far.

Now I can just do `levelplot` from `rasterVis`, but I have to do a slight scaling. This is because the gradient on a real map is computed from heights and distances that have the same units (metres or feet perhaps) but your data is just numbers. Hence the gradients are actually quite small in the natural integer coordinate system. So:

```
vectorplot(r, scaleSlope=.1)
```

gives you:

[image: vector plot]

Note the slope is generally downward, because that's the way your X and Y axes are in your example plot (and hence in my raster). Note also that the cells are square because we are preserving the aspect ratio of the data (because we are treating X and Y coordinates as equal in measure). Ben's answer shows a general L-R flow which means his X and Y coords aren't in the conventional order.

Also, the gradient-finding algorithm in `vectorplot` does some degree of smoothing, so the little discontinuity top right doesn't look as extreme as in Ben's differencing algorithm:

[image]

but you have to decide if you really want to plot the smoothed gradient or the finite differences...

Comment: This is a thing of beauty. I'm still trying to understand both answers to be honest, as I'm new to R. But gosh, this just looks amazing!

Comment: BTW, yes both X and Y are the same unit (length). Sorry to keep you guessing, I didn't think that would be needed.