# raster::rasterToContour; contour lines are not continuous

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, r-raster

I am trying to extract contour lines from a raster object using the `raster` package in R.

`rasterToContour` appears to work well and plots nicely, but when investigated it appears the contour lines are broken up into irregular segments. Example data from `?rasterToContour`

```
library(raster)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
x <- rasterToContour(r)
class(x)
plot(r)
plot(x, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I am trying to extract the contour line of a sample site in the raster. So, we choose a random site, extract its elevation, and run `rasterToContour()` again, specifying the elevation for the contour line `level`.

```
# our sample site - a random cell chosen on the raster
xyFromCell(r, 5000) %>%
  SpatialPoints(proj4string = crs(r)) %>%
  {. ->> site_sp} %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  {. ->> site_sf}

# find elevation of sample site, and extract contour lines
extract(r, site_sf) %>%
  {. ->> site_elevation}

# extract contour lines
r %>%
  rasterToContour(levels = site_elevation) %>%
  {. ->> contours_sp} %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  {. ->> contours_sf}

# plot the site and new contour lines (approx elevation 326)
plot(r)
plot(contours_sf, add = TRUE)
plot(site_sf, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
# plot the contour lines and sample site - using sf and ggplot
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = contours_sf)+
  geom_sf(data = site_sf, color = 'red')
```

[image]

Then we use `st_intersects` to find the lines that intersect the site (with a buffer width of 100 to ensure it touches the line). But, this returns all of the contour lines.

```
contours_sf %>%
  filter(
    st_intersects(., site_sf %>% st_buffer(100), sparse = FALSE)[1,]
  ) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

I assume all lines are returned because they appear to be a single `MULTILINESTRING` `sf` object.

```
contours_sf

# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# geometry type:  MULTILINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 178923.1 ymin: 329720 xmax: 181460 ymax: 333412.3
# CRS:            +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
# level                       geometry
# C_1 326.849822998047 MULTILINESTRING ((179619.3 ...
```

So, I have split the `contours_sf` `MULTILINESTRING` into individual lines using `ngeo::st_segments()` (I couldn't find any `sf` way to do this, but am open to using alternative methods, especially if this is the problem).

Unexpectedly this returns 394 features; from looking at the figure I would expect approximately 15 separate lines.

```
contours_sf %>%
  nngeo::st_segments()

# Simple feature collection with 394 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 178923.1 ymin: 329720 xmax: 181460 ymax: 333412.3
# CRS:            +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
# First 10 features:
#   level                         result
# 1  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179619.3 329739...
# 2  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179580 329720.4...
# 3  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179540 329720, ...
# 4  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179500 329735.8...
# 5  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179495.3 329740...
# 6  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179460 329764, ...
# 7  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179442.6 329780...
# 8  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179420 329810, ...
# 9  326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179410.2 329820...
# 10 326.849822998047 LINESTRING (179380 329847.3...
```

Then, when we filter to keep only the lines which intersect the site (with a buffer width of 100), only a small section of the expected contour line is returned (red section of line, I assume reflective of the 100 buffer width).

```
contours_sf %>%
  nngeo::st_segments() %>%
  filter(
    # this syntax used as recommended by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025700/13478749
    st_intersects(., site_sf %>% st_buffer(100), sparse = FALSE)
  ) %>%

  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(colour = 'red', size = 3)+
  geom_sf(data = contours_sf)+
  geom_sf(data = site_sf, colour = 'cyan')+
  geom_sf(data = site_sf %>% st_buffer(100), colour = 'cyan', fill = NA)
```

[image]

Anyone got ideas for the following points:

1. Explain why the contour lines are 'broken'
2. Provide an efficient method for 'joining' the broken pieces together
3. An alternative to `nngeo::st_segments()`, if this is in fact the source of the 394 lines not ~15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the MULTILINESTRING to a LINESTRING seems to do what you need:

```
contours_sf %>% st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% 
  filter(st_intersects(., st_buffer(site_sf, 100), sparse=FALSE)[,1]) %>%

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = contours_sf)+
  geom_sf(data = site_sf, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(color = 'pink')
```

[image: Output with pink selected contour]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it works better if you start by disaggregating the lines

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
x <- rasterToContour(r)
x <- disaggregate(x)
```

Or with `terra`

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(f)
x <- as.contour(r)

x
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : lines 
# dimensions  : 8, 1  (geometries, attributes)

x <- disaggregate(x)
x
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : lines 
# dimensions  : 56, 1  (geometries, attributes)
```

And you can continue like this

```
y <- st_as_sf(x)
```

Or like this

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/meuse.tif", package="terra"))
site <- vect(xyFromCell(r, 5000), crs=crs(r))
elevation <- extract(r, site)
v <- disaggregate(as.contour(r, levels=elevation))
i <- which.min(distance(site, v))
vv <- v[i]

plot(r)
lines(v)
lines(vv, col="red", lwd=2)
points(site, col="blue", cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Robert, both of these options work well