# Spatial Points to Polygons query

Tags: r, geospatial, projection, qgis, r-raster

I have a question regarding converting spatial data in R and bringing it from R into QGIS.

I have a GeoTiff of Antarctic sea ice concentration, downloaded from the link below:

https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/databrowser/#day=13&month=10&year=2022&img=%7B%22image%22%3A%22image-1%22%2C%22product%22%3A%22AMSR%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22visual%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22Antarctic3125%22%7D

I want to extract the contour of the sea ice edge (defined as 15%), and then have this contour in a file type that I can open in QGIS and reproject for use in making other maps. My current understanding is that to do this, I would need to convert the contour to a spatial points df, and then convert that to a spatial polygons df which I would then be able to open as a shapefile in QGIS. However, I think I'm going wrong here as I cannot make the conversion with the below code - any suggestions?

```
**This is my current workflow:**

library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(sf)

#Load in sea ice geotiff
sic <- raster('Environmental_Data/SIC/AMSR2/asi-AMSR2-s3125-20220107-v5.4.tif')/1 
plot(sic)

#Make all values over land NA
sic[sic>100] = NA

#Crop to make area smaller (I have a specific area of interest)
sic = crop(sic, extent(sic)*c(0.5,0.5,0,1)) 
plot(sic)

#Pull out the sea ice edge (15% contour) (this makes it a spatial lines df)
ie = rasterToContour(sic, levels=15)

#Convert to spatial points
ie.pt = as(ie, "SpatialPointsDataFrame") plot(ie.pt, add=T, pch=16, cex=0.4)

#Convert to spatial polygons
ie.pt_poly <-as(ie.pt, "SpatialPolygons")

#Then I get this error: 
Error in as(ie.pt, "SpatialPolygons"):
no method or default for coercing “SpatialPointsDataFrame” to “SpatialPolygons”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("asi-AMSR2-s3125-20221113-v5.4.tif")

# crop to the area of interest
e <- ext(-1975000, 1975000, 2e+05, 4350000)
re <- crop(r, e)

# get contour and save to file
v <- as.contour(re, levels=15)
writeVector(v, "contour_lines.shp")
```

Contours are normally lines (neither points nor polygons). But if you wanted a polygon you could do

```
x <- ifel(x <15 | x>100, NA, 1)
p <- as.polygons(x)
writeVector(p, "contour_polygons.shp")
```

Or, more generally, use `terra::classify` to create regions before using `as.polygons`.

Comment: This worked, with the inclusion of some lines to plot the .shp in ggplot:

```
    R <- terra::rast('asi-AMSR2-s3125-20220107- 
          v5.4.tif')/1

    #crop to the area of interest
     e <- ext(-1975000, 1975000, 2e+05, 4350000)
     R_Crop <- crop(tp_max, e)

    #get 15% contour and save to file
    R_v <- as.contour(R_crop, levels=15)
    writeVector(R_v, "15_contour_lines.shp")

    #prep for geom_sf
    R_sf <- R_v %>% st_as_sf()
    R_sf <- R_sf %>% st_transform(target_crs)

    #plot to check
    ggplot()+
    geom_sf(aes(), data = tp_max_sf)

```

Answer (score 1):

reworking your process to `terra` and `sf`...

```
library(terra)
library(sf)
sic <- rast('~/Downloads/asi-AMSR2-s3125-20221113-v5.4.tif')
sic[sic>100] = NA
sic2 = crop(sic, ext(sic)*c(0.5,0.5,0,1))
sic2_contour <- terra::contour(sic2, maxcells=100000, filled = TRUE) # plot side effect
sic2_cont <- as.contour(sic2)
sic2_cont_disagg <- disagg(sic2_cont)
y <- sf::st_as_sf(sic2_cont_disagg)
y
Simple feature collection with 6519 features and 1 field
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -1968608 ymin: 206384.6 xmax: 1968608 ymax: 3660462
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic South
First 10 features:
   level                       geometry
1     10 LINESTRING (-1968608 340765...
2     10 LINESTRING (-1955825 232458...
3     10 LINESTRING (-1968608 259539...
4     10 LINESTRING (-1968608 262189...
5     10 LINESTRING (-1960827 264530...
6     10 LINESTRING (-1968608 265308...
7     10 LINESTRING (-1968608 278293...
8     10 LINESTRING (-1943042 251270...
9     10 LINESTRING (-1943042 275001...
10    10 LINESTRING (-1930259 331948...
unique(y$level)
 [1]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
y10 <- y[which(y$level == 10),]
plot(sic2)
plot(y10, col = 'pink', lwd =3, add = TRUE)
```

I can't think why one would go to points, except perhaps to then buffer and fill one's contour. But `terra::writeRaster(sic2...`, and `terra::writeVector(y,...`, or `y10` pull into QGIS and see.

[image]

There are pink(s) interior to `sic2` as these presumably are holes in sea ice that have the same value as northernmost contour that could perhaps be further removed by testing for `within`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - However, I'm trying to get the margin as a single line. The terra code in your answer plots all of the 15% contours, but I'm trying to retain only the outermost (most northerly) 15% delineation.

Comment: Lengthy discussion on this and short [terra solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579831/rasterrastertocontour-contour-lines-are-not-continuous), that I'll use above, but appears to address both your `raster` and `terra`.